# Google Maps for every single record

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my situation:

I have clinics in database.The problem is that i want to show location for every single clinic in google maps.

I try couple ways but they didn't work.Show only for one clinic not for all.

My question: Is it possible and if is, how?

Thanks in advance(Sorry for my english).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What you want to do is certainly possible, but in order for anyone to help, you'll need to provide some more info (show your code, etc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you should use google maps api for this. This is the php file i am using for similar mission. I can show diffrent cities on map using this. You can get coordinates from database.

Also there is a similar question you should check : [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: 'zcx.jpg'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do is for every div clinic to have google map with marker on it, not one map with all clinics markers.
Is it clear?

Comment: So you can do this in a foreach by putting every clinic coordinate  in a div.